# How to achieve hot-reloading for a chrome browser extension created using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to create a react chrome browser extension using create-react-app. The browser_action popup is pointed to the index.html generated by the react app. The app is ejected from create-react-app and the `writeToDisk` is enabled in the webpack config as well. Initial build and rebuilding on changes are working fine on `npm run start`.

If I make a change in the react code, then close and reopen the browser action popup, the changes are applied. But **hot-reloading** doesn't work as expected. My expectation was that if I kept the browser action window open, and then make a change in the code, the dev build would be rebuilt and the hot reloading would apply live patches on the open browser action popup. But no hot-reloading is happening. Moreover, I get the below error message on the chrome extensions page whenever the browser action window is opened:

[image: Error message for websocket connection establishment]

It seems like the websocket connection required for hot reloading the popup has a problem establishing the connection. Has anyone come across something like this ? All inputs are welcome.. And thanks in advance.

Comment: I would love this to work, but I don't think it's going to be possible because in this scenario Chrome is serving your files.

Comment: Same issue here. Seems Chrome doesn't provide direct websocket connection.